# Parsing process for views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the parsing process for views in rails?  I am partially interested in the *parsing order* with raw html vs ruby code in `erb` tags within views.

I would think this is the order that view code is parsed and eventually sent to the requester:

- a controller calls a view
- The view code gets parsed from top to bottom

  - When rails encounters an `erb` tag *during* the parsing process: rails resolves it and appends the result to the parsed html (this includes `erb` tags referencing helpers)
- Once the entire view is parsed the overall result is sent to the requester

This appears to not be the case.  It appears that the view code does a scan for any `erb` snippets and parses those *first* (including references to helpers).  *After* that is taken care of: rails then parses from top to bottom all the view code and sends the result to the requester.

Take this view for example:

```
# _form.html.erb
<p> Hello World </p>
<p> Foobar </p>
<% if something_is_true %>
  <%= some_helper_method_that_returns_html %>
<% end %>
```

Is this the correct order in how rails figures out views and sends the result to the requester?

- Rails scans the view called on by the controller: as well as any view partials this view references, to see if there are any `erb` snippets

  - For all `erb` snippets those are resolved/transformed into html and appended to the html view
- Rails then parses from top to bottom the view (which at this point the view is an aggregate of itself plus any referenced partials, and all the html that was previously `erb`
- After the view was completely parsed: Rails sends the result to the requester

**Follow up Question**: Is there an order that `erb` tags themselves are resolved?  For example: perhaps an `erb` tag that references a `helper` is resolved first before an `erb` tag that iterates through a collection?  Or: does Rails always just resolve `erb` tags from top to bottom?

Comment: Are you asking about the original `ERB` implementation that comes with Ruby or about `Erubis` the the erb implementation that is used per default in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: @spickermann I didn't know there was a difference.  Let's say the implementation that is in rails.

Comment: Once all the ERB code is parsed (i.e. There is only HTML), what is there to parse? Does your code sample give you different results than what you expected? How do you know?

Comment: @RyanK this question is stemming from a situation I was in where I called a helper method within a `form_for`.  That helper method passed the `form_for` as an argument.  Within that helper I then built fields upon the passed in `form_for` object.  My implementation was causing an infinite loop.  I fixed it by calling the helper only if a virtual attribute I set inside the helper was `true`.  It was a really odd bug, and I figured that I must be missing something with how Rails appends to the buffer prior to sending the buffer to the User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right to think that the view code would be read from top to bottom and processed in that way. But there is a problem with this approach. **ERB** is a template engine/library, and for a template engine to be fast it has to work intelligently.

The process of rendering the action goes something like this:

- Request is passed to the controller
- Before and around filters are ran
- Specified action runs and now Rails know which file to render
- ERB code is picked from the ERB file ignoring all the HTML as Rails does not know anything to do with it
- ERB code is processed in an orderly fashion. For ex:

  ```
  <%= render 'my_header' %>
  This is some HTML
  <%= render 'my_footer' %>
  ```

  In this scenario the file `_my_header.html.erb` would be processed and injected first and then `_my_footer.html.erb` would be processed and injected. ERB tags are resolved from top to bottom.
- This whole file is injected into the layout file in place of `<%= yield %>`
- After filters are ran and around filters are closed
- The data is sent to the client

I hope this clears all your questions about the ERB library.